# Automatically suffix every style with !important

Tags: css, angular, webpack, sass

I'm making a widget in Angular 7 which will be put on different websites. I want this widget to get rid of all the styles which are being applied by that website and then use my own. For that, I'm using cleanslate (http://cleanslatecss.com/) but this means that all my styles will need to be prefixed by !important which I'm okay with because for now, this is the route I want to go (ShadowDOM doesn't work for me for various reasons).

What I wanted to know was, is there any webpack plugin or something else which I could use to suffix all my styles with the `!important` tag at the time of building?

Comment: Finding a webpack plugin is easy. Getting it to work with Angular and for your specific case is hard. We would need to see an example of how you've configured your project. https://github.com/officert/css-important-loader

Comment: http://qnimate.com/dive-into-css-specificity/

Answer (score 2):

[`!important` is a bad practice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), you should instead use CSS selector specificity.

You also have a `all: unset` property, which removes every CSS property from the element it is applied to.

[Be careful about the support though](https://caniuse.com/#search=all).

Comment: I've never heard of `all: unset`. Thank you, this will help me a lot with my own website.

Comment: @Reactgular no problem !

Comment: I'm aware that !important is a bad practice but in my case selector specificity isn't really helping which is why until ShadowDOM is fully developed, I'll have to rely on !Important.

Comment: @HaseebAhmed are you kidding ? Selector specificity is exactly what you need. That's called encapsulating your classes, either by a prefix before it or by CSS concepts like emulation or shadow dom. Besides, it's not your job to override CSS classes of the host : it's the host's dev. I'm serious there, you're starting a widget, don't start with a bad practice !

Comment: @HaseebAhmed If you prefix all your styles with an ID selector it'll have the same effect as `!important`. Keep in mind that `!important` will override inline styles in the DOM. ID selectors are the highest and safest CSS priority.

Comment: @Maryannah As I mentioned before, I don't want to go the Shadow DOM route, we want to support IE11 and Edge but Shadow DOM doesn't have a very good support there and people have had issues with Angular and Shadow DOM on IE11 and Edge. As for selector specificity, I have tried it but it isn't really helping and I have no idea why. To give you a brief idea, what I'm doing is the host is using Bootstrap, than in my ID (#my-container) I've used a modified version of cleanslatecss (without !important) to clean everything and lastly included bootstrap and our customization on top of it.

Comment: Then you should use bootstrap mixins to make your own class. Look, I'm telling you how it is with source from official documentations, if you choose to not listen to it, you're simply poorly coding. I'm not judging, but if you already know what you want to do, why would you even bother to make a question.